# Best Synchronized(Concurrent) HashMap for many get(contains) operations

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

I've read on multiple sites that the `ConcurrentHashMap` is best suited for many put operations but few get.

For my case I need pretty much the reverse thing or a more general suited `HashMap` for multithreaded operations (mostly get and contains but still a lot of put). I would prefer to not use the `synchronized` keyword as it would pretty much remove the advantage of multithreading in my scenario and only make things more complicated.

Comment: See property `concurrencyLevel` on `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: Sounds like the situation for which `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock` was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't refer which sites exactly say this, so we can only guess about how they argumented such conclusion. In general if you asked for existing key and have no collisions, then Java-7 `ConcurrentHashMap.get` implementation has four volatile reads (segments array element, table, table array element, value) and Java-8 has only three volatile reads (table, table array element, value). Every collision adds one more volatile read. Under low contention (no concurrent volatile writes) the volatile read is quite cheap (the matter of nanoseconds), so it's unlikely to make big overhead.

Anyways you should not blindly trust any performance advices. You should profile and benchmark your own application to find the performance bottlenecks. I suggest you to try using `ConcurrentHashMap`, I'm pretty sure it's not that bad for most of applications (though you should not blindly trust my advice as well).

As for `concurrencyLevel` property, please note that it means almost nothing since Java-8. If you're using Java-8, tuning this property is useless.